# setFont in ReportLab, Django

Tags: django, reportlab

I want to set cyrillic font in reportLab for my pdf file. I found some articles about it, for example:

```
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('VeraBI', 'VeraBI.ttf'))

canvas.setFont('Vera', 32)
```

But the issue is that I don't use canvas. I found this view to create a table, and it's not using `canvas`. How to set my font?
`

```
def print_invoice(request, order_id):
    from reportlab.lib import colors
    from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4, inch, landscape
    from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle, Paragraph
    from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
    from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
    from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont
    pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Arimo-Regular', 'static/themes/font/Arimo-Regular.ttf'))
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.pdf"'
    buff = StringIO()
    menu_pdf = SimpleDocTemplate(buff, pagesize=A4, rightMargin=30,leftMargin=30, topMargin=30,bottomMargin=18)
    menu_pdf.pagesize = landscape(A4)
    elements = []
    data = [
    ["fd", "Price per bottle", "Bottles in package",
     "Price for package", "Number of packages", "Total price"],
    ]
    order = Order.objects.get(pk=order_id)
    for item in order.orderproduct_set.all():
        product = item.product
        array = [product.brand.name, str(product.price), str(product.package.product_amount),
                 str(product.package.package_price), str(item.product_amount), str(item.price)]
        data.append(array)
    #TODO: Get this line right instead of just copying it from the docs
    style = TableStyle([('ALIGN',(1,1),(-2,-2),'RIGHT'),
                           ('TEXTCOLOR',(1,1),(-2,-2),colors.red),
                           ('VALIGN',(0,0),(0,-1),'TOP'),
                           ('TEXTCOLOR',(0,0),(0,-1),colors.blue),
                           ('ALIGN',(0,-1),(-1,-1),'CENTER'),
                           ('VALIGN',(0,-1),(-1,-1),'MIDDLE'),
                           ('TEXTCOLOR',(0,-1),(-1,-1),colors.green),
                           ('INNERGRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                           ('BOX', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                           ])
    #Configure style and word wrap
    s = getSampleStyleSheet()
    s = s["BodyText"]
    s.wordWrap = 'CJK'
    data2 = [[Paragraph(cell, s) for cell in row] for row in data]
    t = Table(data2)
    t.setStyle(style)


    #Send the data and build the file
    elements.append(t)
    menu_pdf.build(elements)
    response.write(buff.getvalue())
    buff.close()
    return response
```

Answer (score 2):

May by you can create your own style and use it everywhere? As example:

```
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
    styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Justify', alignment=TA_JUSTIFY, fontName='Times', fontSize=10))
    styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Justify-Bold', alignment=TA_JUSTIFY, fontName='Times-Bold'))
    bold_style = styles['Justify-Bold']
    normal_style = styles['Justify']
```

or:

```
doc_title = copy.copy(styles["Heading1"])
    doc_title.alignment = TA_CENTER
    doc_title.fontName = 'Times-Bold'
    doc_title.fontSize = 16
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Register your font:

```
    pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('DejaVuSerif', 'DejaVuSerif.ttf'))
```

2. In your TableStyle add:

```
    ('FONT', (0, 0), (6, 0), 'DejaVuSerif'),
```